# How to count frequency of elements by row of entire table

Tags: python, pandas

I have a huge dataset of data in excel sheet, the data does not have any columns name and it looks like this.

[image]

Should i use **groupby** and **count** function? so that I could count the frequency of the elements in every row, but I could not find any way on doing so, should I use **Lambda** function? if yes, how can I apply it.

I would also like to be able to group and count the data into four categories which are **0.25, 0.50, 0.75, 1.0** and have the output to look like this

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow A'sri. Before you start, make sure you ask one question at a time. You may want to ask "I would also like to be able to group and count the data into four categories which are 0.25, 0.50, 0.75, 1.0 and have the output to look like this" after you solved your first issue. So that each question is clear and separate. For this thread focus on the groupby.

Comment: I believe you may be confused on how "group by" and "count" work, but I see what you want to do. I don't think groupby and count will do what you want. Before we continue, I advise that you ask "what result" you want and avoid using "how you think it is supposed to be done" (group by, count) so as to avoid any confusion. you should reformat your question.

Comment: To make it simple: Do you just want to count the frequency of all [0.0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1.0] (entire table)? Or do you want frequency "by row" or "by columns"?

Comment: my bad sorry. I would like to count the frequency of all [0.0, 0.25,0.5,0.75,1.0] by row of entire table

Answer (score 1):

```
# This is not the most "efficient solution", it is meant to be easy for newcomers.

import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter

# Example data.
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(a = [1,2,3,1,2,3], b = [1,1,1,2,2,2]))

# Put all numbers in your dataframe into "my_list".
my_list = []
df.applymap(lambda x: my_list.append(x))

# Give this list to Counter and counter will count the frequencies for you.
counter = Counter(my_list)
# Prints frequencies: "Counter({1: 5, 2: 5, 3: 2})" 
print(counter)
```

More info: [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), [pandas.DataFrame.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html), [pandas.DataFrame.applymap](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html), [lambdas](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/anonymous-function).